# Query for user rank suddenly stopped working?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query here that I was using for finding user's rank:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank 
  FROM users 
 WHERE xp>=(SELECT xp FROM users uid='?') 
   AND createdate<=(SELECT createdate FROM users WHERE uid='?')
```

The intended purpose is to rank users by xp - createdate; if two users have 100xp and we need to assign an individual rank, their creation dates will be compared ONLY after their xp has been determined the same.  In this case, the team with the oldest create date gets assigned the higher rank.

It used to work *perfectly* until after I've updated to newest MySQLi (5.6.34) For whatever reason, it seems now that createdate has precedence over xp.

I am now wondering if the problem is related to my logic.  I'm just absolutely perplexed as it was working fine before for the purpose intended (finding the user's unique rank) but now it's just sort of randomly assigning rank's regardless of values for create date and xp.

Comment: Somehow I don't believe that `FROM users uid='1'` has ever been a valid syntax.

Comment: I'm perplexed as to how it ever worked also.  All that query returns is a number.  I shows no user info.

Comment: this is about the query, obviously it would be '?' followed by a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your query (fixed missing "WHERE" keyword in the first subquery)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank 
FROM users 
WHERE xp>=(SELECT xp FROM users WHERE uid='1') 
  AND createdate<=(SELECT createdate FROM users WHERE uid='1')
```

then it has never been correct. You have either been lucky that `xp` correlated with `createdate`. Or you just didn't realize that it returned wrong results. Note that the first registered user (lowest `createdate`) would always have rank 1, because `createdate<=(SELECT createdate FROM users WHERE uid='1')` can only return one row (which is the row of the same user).

What you can use is something like this:

```
select count(*) as rank
from users u0
join users u 
  on u.xp > u0.xp
  or u.xp = u0.xp and u.createdate <= u0.createdate
where u0.uid = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct logic using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM users u2
              WHERE u.xp > u2.xp OR
                    (u.xp = u2.xp AND u.createddate <= u2.createdDate) AND
                    u2.uid = ?
             ) ;
```